# Gson: Cannot deserialization Joda Time LocalDateTime value properly in Android

Tags: java, android, jackson, gson, jodatime

I have an HTTP REST API running on a Java web server (Jersey Jax RS RI 2.13), that provides me an `ArrayList` of my `AssetBooking` objects serialised with Jackson. On the Android side, I have the same object, which I deserialise with Gson.

All other objects are deserialised just fine, and the other fields of the `AssetBooking` object are deserialised just fine as well...

This is my deserialisation method:

```
public ArrayList<AssetBooking> getAssetBookings (String json) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        ArrayList<AssetBooking> assetBookings = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<AssetBooking>>(){}.getType());

        return assetBookings;

    }
```

The problem is that my Joda Time `LocalDateTime` fields are getting deserialised with current time stamp, and not with the dates I am passing from the server (which are correct in the JSON string).

**Would you know the possible cause of the issue?**

#### AssetBooking.java

```java
import org.joda.time.*;

public class AssetBooking {

    protected int id;
    protected int assetId;
    protected int userId;
    protected LocalDateTime fromDatetime;
    protected LocalDateTime toDatetime;
    protected boolean status;
    protected LocalDateTime createdOn;
    protected LocalDateTime updatedOn;
    protected String userName;
    protected String userLastName;
    protected String userEmail;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAssetId() {
        return assetId;
    }

    public void setAssetId(int assetId) {
        this.assetId = assetId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getFromDatetime() {
        return fromDatetime;
    }

    public void setFromDatetime(LocalDateTime fromDatetime) {
        this.fromDatetime = fromDatetime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getToDatetime() {
        return toDatetime;
    }

    public void setToDatetime(LocalDateTime toDatetime) {
        this.toDatetime = toDatetime;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(LocalDateTime createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedOn() {
        return updatedOn;
    }

    public void setUpdatedOn(LocalDateTime updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserLastName() {
        return userLastName;
    }

    public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }
}
```

JSON string as received at the Android side (it has only one object but I had to cut date variables `createdOn` and `updatedOn` so it would not blow the StackOverflow maximum post size):

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "assetId": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "fromDatetime": {
            "year": 2017,
            "dayOfMonth": 12,
            "dayOfWeek": 1,
            "era": 1,
            "dayOfYear": 163,
            "chronology": {
                "zone": {
                    "fixed": true,
                    "id": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "centuryOfEra": 20,
            "yearOfEra": 2017,
            "yearOfCentury": 17,
            "weekyear": 2017,
            "monthOfYear": 6,
            "weekOfWeekyear": 24,
            "hourOfDay": 13,
            "minuteOfHour": 14,
            "secondOfMinute": 15,
            "millisOfSecond": 0,
            "millisOfDay": 47655000,
            "fields": [
                {
                    "lenient": false,
                    "minimumValue": -292275054,
                    "maximumValue": 292278993,
                    "leapDurationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "rangeDurationField": null,
                    "durationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 31556952000,
                        "name": "years",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "name": "year",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": null,
                        "name": "year"
                    },
                    "supported": true
                },
                {
                    "lenient": false,
                    "minimumValue": 1,
                    "maximumValue": 12,
                    "leapDurationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "rangeDurationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 31556952000,
                        "name": "years",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "durationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 2629746000,
                        "name": "months",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "name": "monthOfYear",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "name": "monthOfYear"
                    },
                    "supported": true
                },
                {
                    "minimumValue": 1,
                    "maximumValue": 31,
                    "rangeDurationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 2629746000,
                        "name": "months",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "lenient": false,
                    "durationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "unitMillis": 86400000,
                    "name": "dayOfMonth",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "name": "dayOfMonth"
                    },
                    "supported": true,
                    "leapDurationField": null
                },
                {
                    "maximumValue": 86399999,
                    "range": 86400000,
                    "rangeDurationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "lenient": false,
                    "durationField": {
                        "name": "millis",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "millis"
                        },
                        "supported": true,
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 1
                    },
                    "minimumValue": 0,
                    "unitMillis": 1,
                    "name": "millisOfDay",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "millis"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "name": "millisOfDay"
                    },
                    "supported": true,
                    "leapDurationField": null
                }
            ],
            "values": [
                2017,
                6,
                12,
                47655000
            ],
            "fieldTypes": [
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "years"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": null,
                    "name": "year"
                },
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "months"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": {
                        "name": "years"
                    },
                    "name": "monthOfYear"
                },
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "days"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": {
                        "name": "months"
                    },
                    "name": "dayOfMonth"
                },
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "millis"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": {
                        "name": "days"
                    },
                    "name": "millisOfDay"
                }
            ]
        },
        "toDatetime": {
            "year": 2017,
            "dayOfMonth": 13,
            "dayOfWeek": 4,
            "era": 1,
            "dayOfYear": 194,
            "chronology": {
                "zone": {
                    "fixed": true,
                    "id": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "centuryOfEra": 20,
            "yearOfEra": 2017,
            "yearOfCentury": 17,
            "weekyear": 2017,
            "monthOfYear": 7,
            "weekOfWeekyear": 28,
            "hourOfDay": 14,
            "minuteOfHour": 15,
            "secondOfMinute": 16,
            "millisOfSecond": 0,
            "millisOfDay": 51316000,
            "fields": [
                {
                    "lenient": false,
                    "minimumValue": -292275054,
                    "maximumValue": 292278993,
                    "leapDurationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "rangeDurationField": null,
                    "durationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 31556952000,
                        "name": "years",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "name": "year",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": null,
                        "name": "year"
                    },
                    "supported": true
                },
                {
                    "lenient": false,
                    "minimumValue": 1,
                    "maximumValue": 12,
                    "leapDurationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "rangeDurationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 31556952000,
                        "name": "years",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "durationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 2629746000,
                        "name": "months",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "name": "monthOfYear",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": {
                            "name": "years"
                        },
                        "name": "monthOfYear"
                    },
                    "supported": true
                },
                {
                    "minimumValue": 1,
                    "maximumValue": 31,
                    "rangeDurationField": {
                        "precise": false,
                        "unitMillis": 2629746000,
                        "name": "months",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "lenient": false,
                    "durationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "unitMillis": 86400000,
                    "name": "dayOfMonth",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": {
                            "name": "months"
                        },
                        "name": "dayOfMonth"
                    },
                    "supported": true,
                    "leapDurationField": null
                },
                {
                    "maximumValue": 86399999,
                    "range": 86400000,
                    "rangeDurationField": {
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 86400000,
                        "name": "days",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "supported": true
                    },
                    "lenient": false,
                    "durationField": {
                        "name": "millis",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "millis"
                        },
                        "supported": true,
                        "precise": true,
                        "unitMillis": 1
                    },
                    "minimumValue": 0,
                    "unitMillis": 1,
                    "name": "millisOfDay",
                    "type": {
                        "durationType": {
                            "name": "millis"
                        },
                        "rangeDurationType": {
                            "name": "days"
                        },
                        "name": "millisOfDay"
                    },
                    "supported": true,
                    "leapDurationField": null
                }
            ],
            "values": [
                2017,
                7,
                13,
                51316000
            ],
            "fieldTypes": [
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "years"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": null,
                    "name": "year"
                },
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "months"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": {
                        "name": "years"
                    },
                    "name": "monthOfYear"
                },
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "days"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": {
                        "name": "months"
                    },
                    "name": "dayOfMonth"
                },
                {
                    "durationType": {
                        "name": "millis"
                    },
                    "rangeDurationType": {
                        "name": "days"
                    },
                    "name": "millisOfDay"
                }
            ]
        },
        "status": true,
        "userName": "Fabio",
        "userLastName": "Lanza",
        "userEmail": "fabio@blabla.bla"
    }
]
```

As an experiment I serialised the object (not the array) after its deserialisation and had this result:

```
{
  "assetId": 1,
  "createdOn": {
    "iChronology": {
      "iBase": {
        "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
      }
    },
    "iLocalMillis": 1492419018809
  },
  "fromDatetime": {
    "iChronology": {
      "iBase": {
        "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
      }
    },
    "iLocalMillis": 1492419014536
  },
  "id": 0,
  "status": true,
  "toDatetime": {
    "iChronology": {
      "iBase": {
        "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
      }
    },
    "iLocalMillis": 1492419018793
  },
  "updatedOn": {
    "iChronology": {
      "iBase": {
        "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
      }
    },
    "iLocalMillis": 1492419018831
  },
  "userEmail": "fabio@blabla.bla",
  "userId": 1,
  "userLastName": "Lanza",
  "userName": "Fabio"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is very bloated without a reason. Note that not very every class is designed to be (de)serialized, especially with non-standard libraries like Jackson or Gson (any reason of why Joda Time should care for both Gson and Jackson itself?). These two libraries are smart enough to (de)serialize using Java reflection, but they have no any idea if the given class is justified to be (de)serialized. Things can go even worse if you use different versions of the same libraries on both sides because you cannot be sure that those objects are binary compatible. Even more: you should never make any assumptions on a particular object binary structure and use its public API only *for your good*. All you have to do is making those libraries aware of such classes and define the way their instances are (de)seriaized.

For simplicity, you can encode/decode `LocalDateTime` instances using strings: it's the simplest way and works with Joda Time just perfect:

- `LocalDateTime.toString()` to encode;
- `LocalDateTime.parse()` to decode.

For example, a simple value `new LocalDateTime(2017, 4, 16, 17, 15)` can be "toStringed" as `2017-04-16T17:15:00.000`. And that's enough to restore the original date from it. Of course, you can use custom formatters if necessary.

#### "Server"

```java
final class Server {

    private Server() {
    }

    static InputStream produceResponse()
            throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        objectMapper.writeValue(byteArrayOutputStream, payload);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    }

    private static final LocalDateTime date = new LocalDateTime(2017, 4, 16, 17, 15);

    private static final List<AssetBookingJacksonDto> payload = ImmutableList.of(
            new AssetBookingJacksonDto(1, 10, 100, date, date, true, date, date, "foo", "bar", "foo.bar@email")
    );

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = createObjectMapper();

    private static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Here we just define that we don't need getters and will use fields for brevity   
        return objectMapper
                .setVisibility(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                        .withFieldVisibility(ANY)
                        .withGetterVisibility(NONE)
                        .withSetterVisibility(NONE)
                        .withCreatorVisibility(NONE)
                )
                // Here is where LocalDateTime serialization strategy is registered
                .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                        .addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer())
                );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final class AssetBookingJacksonDto {

        private final int id;
        private final int assetId;
        private final int userId;
        private final LocalDateTime fromDatetime;
        private final LocalDateTime toDatetime;
        private final boolean status;
        private final LocalDateTime createdOn;
        private final LocalDateTime updatedOn;
        private final String userName;
        private final String userLastName;
        private final String userEmail;

        private AssetBookingJacksonDto(final int id, final int assetId, final int userId, final LocalDateTime fromDatetime, final LocalDateTime toDatetime,
                final boolean status, final LocalDateTime createdOn, final LocalDateTime updatedOn, final String userName, final String userLastName,
                final String userEmail) {
            this.id = id;
            this.assetId = assetId;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.fromDatetime = fromDatetime;
            this.toDatetime = toDatetime;
            this.status = status;
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
            this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.userLastName = userLastName;
            this.userEmail = userEmail;
        }

    }

    private static final class LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer
            extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(final LocalDateTime localDateTime, final JsonGenerator generator, final SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException {
            // Just encode it's as a simple string -- this is all you need
            generator.writeString(localDateTime.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

#### "Client"

```java
final class Client {

    private Client() {
    }

    static void consumeResponse(final Reader reader) {
        final List<AssetBookingGsonDto> payload = gson.fromJson(reader, assetBookingListType);
        for ( final AssetBookingGsonDto assetBooking : payload ) {
            System.out.println(assetBooking.assetId + ": " + assetBooking.createdOn);
        }
    }

    // TypeToken.getType() results are constant and can be saved to re-use  
    private static final Type assetBookingListType = new TypeToken<List<AssetBookingGsonDto>>() {
    }.getType();

    // Gson instantiation may take some time, and Gson is thread-safe, so we can re-use it too
    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            // Note that nullSafe() method
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeAdapter().nullSafe())
            .create();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final class AssetBookingGsonDto {

        // I prefer not to use getters/setters for DTO data bags
        // * final can be stripped off by Gson -- not a problem
        // * primitive fields cannot be null, but simple 0 and false would cause inlining by javac (0 and false are constaants), so we're cheating javac
        private final int id = Integer.valueOf(0);
        private final int assetId = Integer.valueOf(0);
        private final int userId = Integer.valueOf(0);
        private final LocalDateTime fromDatetime = null;
        private final LocalDateTime toDatetime = null;
        private final boolean status = Boolean.valueOf(false);
        private final LocalDateTime createdOn = null;
        private final LocalDateTime updatedOn = null;
        private final String userName = null;
        private final String userLastName = null;
        private final String userEmail = null;

    }

    private static final class LocalDateTimeAdapter
            extends TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final LocalDateTime value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            // Now just decode the string
            return LocalDateTime.parse(in.nextString());
        }

    }

}
```

#### Example

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(produceResponse()) ) {
        consumeResponse(reader);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 10: 2017-04-16T17:15:00.000

Also, responses for both "pre-custom-serializers" and "custom-serializers" scenarios (pretty-printed, the lengths were calculated before pretty-printing):

#### before.json, 656 bytes

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "assetId": 10,
        "userId": 100,
        "fromDatetime": {
            "iLocalMillis": 1492362900000,
            "iChronology": {
                "iBase": {
                    "iBase": null,
                    "iParam": null,
                    "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
                },
                "iParam": null
            }
        },
        "toDatetime": {
            "iLocalMillis": 1492362900000,
            "iChronology": {
                "iBase": {
                    "iBase": null,
                    "iParam": null,
                    "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
                },
                "iParam": null
            }
        },
        "status": true,
        "createdOn": {
            "iLocalMillis": 1492362900000,
            "iChronology": {
                "iBase": {
                    "iBase": null,
                    "iParam": null,
                    "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
                },
                "iParam": null
            }
        },
        "updatedOn": {
            "iLocalMillis": 1492362900000,
            "iChronology": {
                "iBase": {
                    "iBase": null,
                    "iParam": null,
                    "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
                },
                "iParam": null
            }
        },
        "userName": "foo",
        "userLastName": "bar",
        "userEmail": "foo.bar@email"
    }
]
```

#### after.json, 272 bytes

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "assetId": 10,
        "userId": 100,
        "fromDatetime": "2017-04-16T17:15:00.000",
        "toDatetime": "2017-04-16T17:15:00.000",
        "status": true,
        "createdOn": "2017-04-16T17:15:00.000",
        "updatedOn": "2017-04-16T17:15:00.000",
        "userName": "foo",
        "userLastName": "bar",
        "userEmail": "foo.bar@email"
    }
]
```

Pretty self-descriptive.